# Insert snippet in mac LaunchDaemon

Tags: install4j

install4j has the option to insert custom fragments into plist files. I cannot get my head around to make it work. The launcher is a mac service. My custom fragment is

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
      <key>SERVICE_HOME</key>
      <string>/Users/Shared/MyService/Home</string>
      <key>JAVA_HOME</key>
      <string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/</string>
</dict>
```

But it is ignored with no hint in the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install4j generates service executables on Mac OS X as Unix shell scripts and not as Mac OS application bundles, so the Info.plist fragment is not inserted in that case.

Instead, you have to add the definition of the environment variables as a shell script on the "Executable info->Unix options" step of the launcher wizard:

```
export SERVICE_HOME=/Users/Shared/MyService/Home
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Comment: I would have expected though that in the case of a mac service that the plist fragment was inserted in launchd plist file and not silently ignored. I recognize however that in the provided example it works.